# retrieve attribute from object in entity doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, lazy-loading

So I have this function :

```
MyProject\Bundle\Entity\Audio;

/**
 * 
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getStudioName()
{
   return $this->getStudio()->getNom();
}
```

which is supposed to retrieve the attribute `nom` from the object Studio.

They are defined like this :

```
/**
 * @var \MyProject\Bundle\Entity\Device
 */

private $studio;

...

/**
 * Get studio
 *
 * @return \MyProject\Bundle\Entity\Device
 */
public function getStudio()
{
    return $this->studio;
}
```

And the `->getNom` is just also a basic return, which works fine.

So i get that following error message :

> Error: Call to a member function getNom() on a non-object

I've read about lazy loading and I understand why `$this->getStudio()` gives me a proxy instead of an actual Device object, but I can't go further and use `getNom()` after that...
I've tried to add `fetch : EAGER` to avoid lazy loading but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you pass code for whole entity? It looks like property `$studio` can be NULL. In such a case, you need to validate if it is set. If not, return NULL.

Comment: Wow it worked. Thanks a lot ! (Just spent 2 hours on this...)

Here is the code :


    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */ 
    public function getStudioName()
    {
        $data = $this->getStudio();
        if(!is_null($data))
        {
       return $data->getNom();
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Great, I'm happy it helped you :). I've posted complete answer, so this can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like property `$studio` can be NULL. In such a case, you need to validate if it is set. If not, return NULL.

The real code would look like this:

```
<?php 

public function getStudioName(): ?string
{
    return $this->studio ? $this->studio->getName() : null;
}
```

Comment: `public function getStudioName() { return (!$this->studio) ?: $this->studio->getName(); }`

Comment: I think it is a better way to test if $this->studio is an instance of a class which implements the getName() method.

`if ($this->studio instanceof MyProject\Bundle\Entity\Audio)`

Comment: `$studio` can be only `NULL` or `Audio`. The value should be checked in another place, like constructor or setter, by typehint.

Comment: @scoolnico Thanks for the tip, I've updated code with inline condition.